# 1.7 displaying products placed in a root category

Tags: product, category, magento-1.7

I've built a new block that displays products placed in a specific category (chosen via ID) and renders them out with some fancy jQuery. Now to test this I passed a id of 17, a category with plenty of products 10+. All works fine, products are found and rendered out propperly.

If i however pass it the id for a root category (I have called featured products) that has 6 products in, it fails to work.

```
    <!-- Global Variables -->
<?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); ?>
<?php $_helper  = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>

<?php 
$featured_category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(17);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($featured_category)
    ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
    ->load();
?>
        <ul>
        <?php $counter = 0; ?>
        <?php foreach($products as $_item): ?>
```

Is there anything major I've done wrong that would stop this from working in a root category but not a sub category?

Comment: What is your root category ID? If its 0 or 1 - then perhaps its being passed as a boolean, not integer

Comment: How did you go with this? If you found a solution then please post your answer.

Comment: I've tested your code myself and it works fine provided the root category has "Is Anchor" set to "No". Can you double check this is the case for you?

Answer (score 4):

I think you may be approaching this from the wrong angle. There is no need to create a new block type, the default **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List** contains all the logic you need within the **_getProductCollection()** method

### Showing root category

**CMS method**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured.products.list" show_root_category="true" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**Layout XML method**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured.products.list" show_root_category="true" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
```

### Showing a nominated category

**CMS method**

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured.products.list" category_id="17" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

**Layout XML method**

```
<block type="catalog/product_list" name="featured.products.list" category_id="17" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"/>
```

### From within any product list block

```
$this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
$items = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

That's all that is needed. Look at Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List::_getProductCollection() to see what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: The method isn't my issue, I am simply trying to get the products from the root category a special way for knowing how to do it's sake.

Comment: Updated my answer with the code for your situation